# glade and pygtk (probably a charset prob?)

Tags: python, character-encoding, arguments, pygtk, glade

I am struggling with a problem, that is really driving me nuts. I installed Pygtk-all-in-one Bundle version 2.24.2 for Python 2.7 [1] and Python 2.7.5 [2].

Now I want to use gtk.builder to load my glade file.

My python file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import gtk

import gtk.glade

class  QueryRelevanceEvaluationApp:

    def __init__(self):
        builder = gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file("C:\blubb.glade")
        builder.connect_signals(self)

app = QueryRelevanceEvaluationApp()
gtk.main()
```

My glade file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.16"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

If I run the application, I get the following error:

```
Process started >>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bernhard\Documents\test\base2.py", line 16, in <module>
    app = QueryRelevanceEvaluationApp()
  File "C:\Users\Bernhard\Documents\test\base2.py", line 13, in __init__
    builder.add_from_file("C:\blubb.glade")
glib.GError: Datei ┬╗Clubb.glade┬½ konnte nicht ge├Âffnet werden: Invalid argument
```

However, If I rename "blubb.glade" to "hallo-welt2.ui" everyhing works fine. I am relatively new to Python, so I don't really know, what's causing the problem. At first, I thought, that something with my Pygtk installation was wrong, but than I discovered the strange behaviour, that everything works fine, after renaming the file. So I am thinking, that maybe something else (charset?) is causing the problem. I am working on a Windows 7 64 bit machine (my system language is german).

It would be really nice, If someone could give me a hint on how I can solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings from Austria

[1] http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.2.win32-py2.7.msi

[2] http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` is a backspace character, AFAIR; you should escape the backslash:

```
>>> print "C:\blubb.glade"
Clubb.glade
>>> print "C:\\blubb.glade"
C:\blubb.glade
```